# Какие компоненты использовать для GUI java.swing

Tags: java, swing, gui, логика

**Как мне добавлять компоненты сверху других компонентов ? Как выравнивать их?**

Проблема заключается в организации панельки , пожалуй попытаюсь объяснить ситуацию.
В общем у меня стоит задача организовать калькулятор по исчислениям секвенций , вам не нужно понимать что это и как они вычисляются , единственное , что вам нужно знать , что их решение идет не через равно , а через сплошные линии в столбик, вверх. Сначала записывается изначальное уравнение(секвенция) , затем через определнную формулу , которую выбирает пользователь , сверху записывается преобразованная формула(секвенция) , задача считается решенной , когда в каждом столбике сверху по обе стороны от знака "|-" (тождественно истино).

Сложность заключается в том , что при помощи этих преобразований зачастую пример делится на 2 , а то и 3 , и превращается в отдельные подзадачи , где каждую нужно решить (т.е и они могут делиться в свою очередь до тех пор пока пользователь не дойдет до нужного шага).

Как мне добавлять компоненты сверху других компонентов ? Как выравнивать их?(В том , плане что над чертой может оказаться 3 компонента , а с ним на том же уровне ,например слева тоже 3 компонента , те что слева могут вытолкнуть тех что справа со своего места и будет сложно понять к какому подкомпоненту они относятся, для этого придется как то выравнивать все компоненты , что находятся на уровень ниже?)И мне надо реализовать выбор этих компонентов , которые находятся на верхних уровнях в своем столбце , чтобы в дальнейшем выбрать формулу и произвести преобразование, которое запишется на уровень выше.

Интересует любая реализация , какой бы кривой она не была. Буду рад любым советам по данному вопросу

[image: решение]

Comment: Менеджер компоновки не решает вашу задачу? GridLayout как мне кажется вполне подходит для нее. В каждой клетке размещаете какой-нибудь контейнер, например JPanel, а в нем уже нужные вам компоненты или же рисуете напрямую то что вам нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) - это сетка с "резиновым" размером строк и столбцов, в которой компонент может занимать несколько ячеек. Достоинством такого решения будет выравнивание строк по высоте в разных ветках расчетов. Недостатки: необходимо самому пересчитывать размеры и положение компонентов на сетке при изменении дерева, и нельзя будет просто реализовать сворачивание части вычислений.

Пример реализации:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.StrokeBorder;


public class GridBagTreeDisplay {

    static class TopLineBorder extends StrokeBorder {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 819507837355280534L;

        public TopLineBorder(BasicStroke stroke) {
            super(stroke);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            float size = this.getStroke().getLineWidth();
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
            g2d.setStroke(this.getStroke());
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.draw( new Line2D.Float( x + size / 2, y + size / 2, width - size, y + size / 2 ) );
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Класс, поддерживающий древовидное отображение с помощью GridBagLayout
     * 
     * Манипуляции с узлами дерева осуществляются непосредственно с экземплярами
     * класса TreeView.TreeNode.
     * 
     * Для отображения изменений нужно вызвать метод update()
     */
    static class TreeView {
        private Container container;

        private TreeNode root;

        public TreeView( Container container ) {
            this.container = container;
            this.container.setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
        }

        public void update() {
            container.removeAll();

            if ( root != null ) {
                root.computeAll( 0 );
                root.layoutComponentsOn( container );
            }

            container.revalidate();
            container.repaint();
        }

        public void setRootComponent( JComponent rootComponent ) {
            Objects.requireNonNull( rootComponent );
            this.root = new TreeNode( null, rootComponent );
        }

        public TreeNode root() {
            return root;
        }

        public Optional<TreeNode> findNodeByComponent( JComponent componentToFind ) {
            return root.findByComponent( componentToFind );
        }

        class TreeNode {
            private JComponent component;

            private int position;
            private int depth;

            private int width;
            private int height;

            private TreeNode parent;
            private List<TreeNode> children = new ArrayList<>();

            TreeNode( TreeNode parent, JComponent component ) {
                this.parent = parent;
                this.component = component;

                this.depth = parent != null ? parent.depth + 1 : 0;
            }

            /**
             * Обновляет высоту и ширину поддерева с корнем в этом узле,
             * рекурсивно обновляя высоту и ширину для поддеревьев
             */
            private void computeSize() {
                if ( children.isEmpty() ) {
                    width = 1;
                    height = 1;
                } else {
                    int sumChildWidth = 0;
                    int maxChildHeight = 0;
                    for ( TreeNode child : children ) {
                        child.computeSize();

                        sumChildWidth += child.width;
                        maxChildHeight = Math.max( maxChildHeight, child.height );
                    }
                    width = sumChildWidth;
                    height = maxChildHeight + 1;
                }
            }

            /**
             * Устанавливает горизонтальную позицию этого узла в сетке
             * и обновляет позиции в поддеревьях
             * 
             * @param newPosition - новая позиция
             */
            private void computePosition( int newPosition ) {
                this.position = newPosition;

                int childLeft = position;
                for ( TreeNode child : children ) {
                     child.computePosition( childLeft );
                     childLeft += child.width; 
                }
            }

            /**
             * обновляет размеры и горизонтальную позицию узла и
             * его поддеревьев
             * 
             * @param newPosition
             */
            private void computeAll( int newPosition ) {
                computeSize();

                computePosition( newPosition );
            }

            public void updateTreeView() {
                TreeView.this.update();
            }

            /**
             * Заменяет текущих детей этого узла на новые,
             * содержащие переданные компоненты
             * 
             * @param components
             */
            public void setChildren( JComponent... components ) {
                children.clear();
                for ( JComponent component : components ) {
                    children.add( new TreeNode( this, component ) );
                }
            }

            public TreeNode parent() {
                return parent;
            }

            public List<TreeNode> children() {
                return Collections.unmodifiableList( children );
            }

            public JComponent component() {
                return component;
            }

            public TreeView treeView() {
                return TreeView.this;
            }

            public Optional<TreeNode> findByComponent( JComponent componentToFind ) {
                if ( this.component == componentToFind ) {
                    return Optional.of( this );
                }

                for ( TreeNode child : children ) {
                    Optional<TreeNode> found = child.findByComponent( componentToFind );
                    if ( found.isPresent() ) return found;
                }

                return Optional.empty();
            }

            /**
             * Размещает компоненты текущего узла и дочерних узлов в
             * переданном контейнере
             * 
             * @param container
             */
            private void layoutComponentsOn( Container container ) {
                if ( !(container.getLayout() instanceof GridBagLayout ) ) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException( "container must use GridBagLayout" );
                }
                layoutComponentsOnRecursive( container, this.height );
            }

            private void layoutComponentsOnRecursive( Container container, int treeHeight ) {
                // параметры размещения компонента:
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints( 
                        position,                      // позиция по горизонтали
                        treeHeight - depth,            // позиция по вертикали
                        width,                         // число ячеек по ширине
                        1,                             // число ячеек по высоте
                        1.0,                           // вес компонента по ширине, при ненулевом весе GridBagLayout
                                                       // постарается занять всю ширину контейнера
                        0,                             // вес по высоте
                        GridBagConstraints.CENTER,     // компонент располагается в центре своей области
                        GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, // и растягивается по горизонтали
                        new Insets( 2, 5, 2, 5 ),      // отступы от краев области
                        0, 0                           // минимальные ширина и высота
                    );

                // компонентам из узлов с детьми устанавливаем границу с линией
                component.setBorder( !children.isEmpty() ? new TopLineBorder( new BasicStroke( 1.0f ) ) : null );

                container.add( component, gbc );

                for ( TreeNode child : children ) {
                    child.layoutComponentsOnRecursive( container, treeHeight );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static JLabel[] makeClickableLabels( TreeView display, String... captions ) {
        JLabel[] labels = Arrays.stream( captions )
                .map( caption -> new JLabel( caption, SwingConstants.CENTER ) )
                .toArray( JLabel[]::new );

        for ( JLabel label : labels ) {
            label.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent event ) {
                    display.findNodeByComponent( (JComponent)event.getComponent() )
                        .ifPresent( node -> {
                            if ( event.isShiftDown() ) {
                                node.setChildren();
                            } else {
                                node.setChildren( makeClickableLabels( display, "left", "center", "right" ) );
                            }
                            display.update();
                        });
                }
            });
        }

        return labels;
    }

    static void initUi() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "" );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );

        JPanel content = new JPanel();

        TreeView treeView = new TreeView( content );

        treeView.setRootComponent( makeClickableLabels( treeView, "root" )[0] );

        TreeView.TreeNode root = treeView.root();
        root.setChildren( makeClickableLabels( treeView, "1-left", "1-right" ) );

        root.children().get( 0 ).setChildren( makeClickableLabels( treeView, "2-left-left", "2-left-center", "2-left-right" ) );
        root.children().get( 1 ).setChildren( makeClickableLabels( treeView, "2-right-center" ) );

        root.children().get( 1 ).children().get( 0 ).setChildren( makeClickableLabels( treeView, "3-right-center-center" ) );

        root.updateTreeView();

        frame.add( content, BorderLayout.CENTER );

        frame.setSize( 800, 600 );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( GridBagTreeDisplay::initUi );
    }

}
```

Результат:

[image: пример работы]

Answer (score 2):

1 вариант. Swing умеет HTML, возможно это будет самый быстрый и простой способ.
2 вариант. Действия следующие, условно представим что графическое представление можно разбить на ячейки.
Ячейку ограничим возможностью размещения в ней только 2х или 1 компонента.
Компоненты в ячейке могут быть только с горизонтальным(лево и право) или вертикальным(верх и низ) разделением, а также без разделения.
Теперь после правил выше получаем следующее(опираясь на цифры с приведенной Вами картинки):
**Начало(1)** будет вертикальной 2х компонентной ячейкой. В "низ" помещается однокомпонентная ячейка в которой размещаем текст. 
В "верх" помещаем горизонтальную 2х компонентную ячейку. В "лево" и "право" помещаем по вертикальной 2х компонентной ячейке.
Теперь в каждой ячейке в "низ" помещаем однокомпонентную ячейку с текстом **(2)**. В верхней части можем продолжить дробление ячейками или вставить текст **конец(3)**.
Получилась "матрешка". Если нужно что бы на шаге **(2)** было 3-4-5 блоков то расширим их горизонтальными ячейками(друг в друге).

Comment: Фокус в том что это уже дерево =) внутри ячейки может быть другая ячейка в которой будет еще куча ячеек. Например чтобы на этапе **(2)** было 3 варианта добавляешь горизонтальную ячейку, в "право" этой ячейки добавляешь еще одну горизонтальную ячейку и получится уже 3 места для вариантов. Если понадобится например расширить места до 4х между 1 и 2м вариантом то берешь все что лежит в ячейке "лево" или "право"(разницы особо нет), засовываешь в новую горизонтальную ячейку в слот "право" и вставляешь эту ячейку на место "лево" или "право"(которую выбрал).